# невозможно работать с бд, пишет:"database is locked" Winforms,SQL, C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sqlite

При выполнении метода

```
private void Mudak()
        {
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnStr);
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("select FIO from BlackList where FIO = '" + txtName.Text + "'", conn);
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
                txtName.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            else
                txtName.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            conn.Close();
        }
```

невозможно работать с бд, пишет:"database is locked
database is locked"
Это происходит, только когда условие if подходит.
Грешу на то,что не закрывается соединение, но почему не пойму

Comment: с дебагером запускал?

Comment: Обернуть `conn`, `command` и `reader` в `using`?

Comment: Покажите строку соединения

Comment: К этой базе параллельно что-то еще подключено?

Comment: string ConnStr = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\db.db;";  Строка подключения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего из того что я вижу происходит примерно следущее: вы несколько раз пытаетесь запросить данные не закрывая соединения/ридера. А так как это SQLite лок делается на таблицу. Для начала я бы обернул все создания соеднинений, чтение и команду в using.

Ну немного оффтопа: лучше не делать Select реквесты через склеивание строки так как возможно сделать SQLInjection ваш запрос (лучше параметры передавать через SQLiteParameter).

Comment: ведь не так сложно было бы написать сниппет с использованием `using`? возможно это еще кому-то поможет, не только автору попробуйте добавить в ответ исправленный код.

Answer (score 0):

Я просто добавил reader.Close();
И все заработало

Comment: Обязательно используйте `using`!

Comment: Да, благодарен за помощь

Comment: `reader.Close();` плохое решение, так как он не отработает в случае возникновения исключения. Либо используйте `using`, либо конструкцию `try-finally`.